# How to install mod_authz_core module for MAMP-installed apache?

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I have an .htaccess with the following directive:

```
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
  Require not ip xx.xx.xxx.xx
</RequireAll>
```

On starting Apache through MAMP I get the following error in my apache logs:

```
Invalid command '<RequireAll', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

My Apache version is 2.4.23, MAMP is 4.1, but it appears that mod_authz_core is not an included module with MAMP.  If this is the cause of the error above, how do I go about installing the mod_authz_core module?

**UPDATE:** 
Turns out I was reading the wrong Apache version for MAMP 4.1.  It is 2.2xx which obviously doesn't support mod_authz_core.  After struggling to find a way to upgrade the Apache that comes with MAMP, I've given up and configured my own "MAMP" using Sierra's prepackaged Apache and homebrew for installing PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably installed and just not loaded. Look for a commented out `LoadModule` line near the top of your main config. Something like:

```
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

Uncomment it and restart Apache. If it's not there, try adding it using the same path format to your existing `LoadModule` directives, based on the above for the module name and file.